# Using a foreach traversal to invoke an asynchronous function, returns the result and the request is not normal?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, foreach

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
async function query(num) {
  let data = await request(url, {num})
  console.log(num, data)
}

  [1, 2].forEach(function(item){
     let _self = this
     (function(item) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            _self.query(item)
            console.log(item)
        }, i)
      })(item)
  })

// if the server response
server.get('*', function(req, res) {
 let num = req.num
 res.send(num)
})
```

the async query response is:
    // 1, 2
    // 2, 1

but expectation response is 
    // 1, 1
    // 2, 2
how can i get the desired results?
How does the request parameter agree with the return result?

Comment: You're missing a semicolon (or few), which is going to cause unexpected behavior or errors.

Comment: What's the purpose of the IIFE. Seems very unnecessary. And the `let _self = this` is odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to execute the queries *serially*, not in parallel. So, the start of each iteration should wait for the resolution of the previous iteration before starting. Use `await` with either `for..of` or `reduce`. You can't execute queries in series with `forEach`.

```js
const requests = [1, 2];
const resolveWithArg = function(arg) {
  return new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('resolving with ' + arg);
    res(arg);
  }, 1000))
}


requests.reduce(async(lastPromise, arg) => {
  // the reducer function isn't actually running sequentially itself, it's that they all run immediately, but await the resolve of the previous iteration on the first line
  await lastPromise;
  const result = await resolveWithArg(arg);
  console.log('got result ' + result);
}, Promise.resolve());
```

Comment: When answers work for you, please upvote and Accept them to indicate to other users that it solved your problem :)

Comment: ok，i am already up vote it； I wonder if this is what you mean? this is my first question on stackoverflow,